# THREE.js raycaster not finding any intersects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a simple scene with a plane, and I'm trying to use a ray caster to find where the plane intersects with a vector from below. Whatever I try, there are never any intersections. Any ideas as to what is wrong with this?

Here is the relevant code and [a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/82vJejieikNKzgr4mG9o?p=preview). The arrow below shoots through the plane, so there should be some intersection there...

```
var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 200, 200 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x2194ce, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
geom.computeFaceNormals();
mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(mesh)

var p1 = new THREE.Vector3(100, -20, 100);
var p2 = new THREE.Vector3(100, 10000, 100);
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(p2.clone().normalize(), p1, 150, 0xFFFFFF);
scene.add(arrow)

var direction = new THREE.Vector3 (0, 1, 0);
raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(p1, direction);
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);
console.log(intersects) //nada
```

Comment: if you add `renderer.render(scene, camera);` before `var intersects = raycaster...`, you'll get intersection

Comment: yeah that does seem to work! Gracias